# If $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $f(q)=0 \forall q \in \mathbb{Q}$, prove that $f(x)=0 \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

If $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $f(q)=0 \forall q \in \mathbb{Q}$, prove that $f(x)=0 \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

**Note:** I have to prove this with the help of usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$ and without using the sequential criteria for continuity.

Here's my attempt:

From given definition of f, $f^{-1}(\{0\})=\mathbb{Q}$ at least.

But $\{0\}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ is not.

Continuous maps take closed sets to closed sets, so $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ must be a superset of $\mathbb{Q}$ which is closed.

The only such set if $\mathbb{R}$, so $f^{-1}(\{0\})=\mathbb{R}$, i.e. $f(x)=0 \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

Is this correct?

Comment: We know that $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is a closed subset in $\mathbb{R}$ containing $\mathbb{Q}$. How do you know that $f^{-1}(\{0\})=\mathbb{R}$? That's the key point. If you accept this fact $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}=\mathbb{R}$, it becomes quite trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a well known result that holds for topological spaces $X,Y$:

> Consider $2$ functions $f,g:X \to Y$  and $A \subseteq X $where $A$ is
>   dense in $X$ and $Y$ is Haussdorf. If $f$ and $g$ are equal on $A$,
>   then they are equal everywhere.

Now, apply this theorem to $f$ and $g = 0$, and note that the rationals are dense in the reals (and that any metric space is Hausdorff)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question since it's what the OP want to prove (in a less general case).

Comment: This is kinda like proving the Cauchy Criterion by referring to some result on Banach spaces.

Comment: Seems like the OP found this answer to be satisfying as he accepted it though...

Answer (score 0):

Suppose by contradiction, there is $r\in \mathbb R\backslash \mathbb Q$ s.t. $f(r)\neq 0$. Soppose WLOG that $f(r)>0$. Using continuity, there is a $\delta>0$ s.t. $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in ]r-\delta,r+\delta[$. Since $\mathbb Q$ dense in $\mathbb R$, there is a $q\in\mathbb Q\cap ]x-\delta,x+\delta[$. In particular, $f(q)>0$, contradiction.

Comment: I specifically mentioned that I needed this proved without using the sequential criteria of continuity

Comment: @Diya: Sorry, I didn't see that. Here an other proof with out using sequential continuity.